# Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey userscript for hiding elements by its properties

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts, adblock

there is a block with ads, and css styles are dynamically changed (css obfuscated / minimized) every time the page is loaded, thats why it is not possible to block element traditionally, due to their randomly assigned styles.

looking through the inspector in mozilla firefox, I found out, that there are some css styles with normal names, and they are applied to the DIV along with obfuscated styles. see the screenshot with example.

[screenshot of original site with inspector opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNndp.jpg)

I found out that sometimes Greasemonkey userscripts are more flexible and useable to block particular elements in difficult cases than ublock origin. Especially with AJAX stuff and some other cases. I searched many hours, there are many userscripts here, which do hide elements, but I still have some questions...

I tried to use this script (based on results I found here):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Remove colomn with ads 
// @match     https://e.mail.ru/*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
$('.layout_right-size_60').remove();
$('.layout__column_right').remove();
```

But it also didn't work. I guess, because these styles are "greyed-out" and do not present at source code of the page, I see them only inside mozilla's "inspector". All the styles that are seen in page source code, are obfuscated, as well as elements ID's. None of the simple ways to select elements ain't working here... But I am not sure that the reason is in that.

If selection by css style name is not possible, additional question appeared: how can I select and remove elements (with javascript or jquery), according not only to class name, but to other parameters? for example, according to their "style" properties:

```
width:240px;
padding-left: 8px;
font-size: calc(-82px + 84px + -21px + 30px);
```

...to add this selection to my script above, and remove those elements matching selection. 
I tried that code:

```
$('div[width="240"]').remove();
$('div[style*="width: 240px"]').remove();
```

but no result. maybe, because these elements are dynamically added all the time after the page was already loaded. (just a guess)
[screenshot with code showing 240px property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06542.jpg)

thanks!

PS: I am not programmer, and javascript is not my speciality. I just write custom ublock origin rules for myself, and some basic greasemonkey scripts to hide ads and annoying stuff at websites, cause ads and different popups, etc, getting more and more agressive, and basic adlists from adblocker do not help; I have to fight with ads "per site" individually. Alas.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the text content of the CSS style tag on the page that has that `width: 240px` part? You can see it if you View Source and control-F (or search from Inspector) Not the *calculated* rules you can see on the right when selecting the element, but the *plain text* on the page that results in those rules (around line 1441)

Comment: @CertainPerformance, there is code 'style="width: 240px' straight in the source code, here is screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMlpX.jpg

Comment: Oh, it's applied directly to the element? That would make this pretty trivial, but it wasn't like that in your first screenshot - it sounds like there's a `<style>` tag in the HTML with `width: 240px` in it

Comment: @CertainPerformance, it might be trivial at first glance, but for some reason I can't block element according to this width:240px property. Neither with xpath, nor with jquery. I wonder why.

Comment: I'm not sure about the situation. *If* the CSS style is always being applied directly to the element, it's pretty easy, *but* your first screenshot looks to show that the CSS style is *not* being applied directly to the element (and for a solution to that, the solution I have in mind involves being able to see the inline `<style>` tag)

Comment: there are several nested DIVS, majority of them do not have "style" tag in code. but I found out a few DIVs with that "width" property, and thought that it would be a good chance to "catch" and block them. but it didn't work. and I am puzzled with that. another screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/06542.jpg